# Ruby On Rails - Will Paginate - Next button stuck on page 2 - Array & Activemodel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, neo4j, activemodel

I have the latest will_paginate gem (3.0.4) "working" with ROR 3.2  .. I'm using an array created from an ActiveModel object (using Neo4j for data)...  Well, it mostly works.. I get the following:

```
← Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 … 28 29 Next →
```

However, 1 is selected by default, but clicking next always goes to page 2.. I can click on page 9 and click next and it goes back to page 2.. The NEXT button always links to /albums/show2/266?page=2 no matter what I try

The individual page buttons work fine except 10 11 12 etc never shows.. the dots are constant.. Previous NEVER works..

my controller (excuse the hard coding.. this is experimentation)

```
require 'will_paginate'
require 'will_paginate/array'

def show2
    current_page=params[:page]
    per_page=5

    total_entries = Album.get_album_contents_count(261, 88, current_page, per_page)


    #Album.get_album_contents returns an array of hashes... no problem getting the data this way


    new_results = Album.get_album_contents(261, 88, current_page, per_page)

    @entries = WillPaginate::Collection.create(1, 5, total_entries) do |pager|
    # inject the result array into the paginated collection:
    pager.replace(new_results)
    pager.total_entries = total_entries
    @photos=pager
end
```

the code from my view:

```
<div id="photos">
<%= render "photo"%>    
</div>
<%=will_paginate @photos%>
```

Like I said, it partially works, photos are displayed, etc, and I have endless scrolling working as well.. only problem is.. it only servers up page 2 on endless scrolling also, which basically calls on the NEXT button.  (The endless page didn't cause any problems - this problem existed before I added the endless page functionality)

Any ideas as to how to get this work completely?  I've already gem uninstalled and gem installed it, etc, to no avail...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I've opened an issue - https://github.com/dnagir/neo4j-will_paginate/issues/4 Looks like it should be easy to reproduce this bug (?)

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not using neo4j.rb or jRuby.. just ROR and NEO4j via rest...